# Incomplete dictionary when trying to convert literal directory tree

Tags: python

I have the following python script:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env nix-shell
#! nix-shell -i python -p python3Packages.rich

from pathlib import Path
from rich.pretty import pprint

tree = """
a
├───b
│   └───c
├───d
├───e
│   ├───f
│   │   ├───g
│   │   ├───h
│   │   ├───i
│   │   └───j
│   ├───k
│   ├───l
│   ├───m
│   ├───n
│   │   ├───o
│   │   ├───p
│   │   └───q
│   └───r
├───s
│   ├───t
│   │   └───u
│   ├───v
│   │   ├───w
│   │   └───x
│   └───y
└───z
"""


def parse(tree, completed=[]):
    dct = {}
    tree = (
        tree.strip().split("\n") if isinstance(tree, (str, bytes, bytearray)) else tree
    )
    for index, line in enumerate(tree):
        if line not in completed:
            completed.append(line)
            count = line.count(" ")

            # TODO: Why does this complete dct...
            prefix = "───"
            drv = Path(line[line.find(prefix) :].removeprefix(prefix).split(" ")[0])

            try:
                next_line = tree[index + 1]
                next_count = next_line.count(" ")

                # TODO: And not this?
                # prefix = "───"
                # drv = Path(line[line.find(prefix) :].removeprefix(prefix).split(" ")[0])

            except IndexError:
                dct[drv] = None
                return dct
            else:
                if next_count < count:
                    dct[drv] = None
                    return dct
                elif (prefix not in line) or (next_count > count):
                    dct[drv] = parse(tree[index + 1 :], completed=completed)
                else:
                    dct[drv] = None
    return dct


pprint(parse(tree))
```

Where the first instance of the following block (under the comments in the code above) completes the dictionary of paths, while the second instance does not:

```py
prefix = "───"
drv = Path(line[line.find(prefix) :].removeprefix(prefix).split(" ")[0])
```

Here is the output with the first instance commented:

```py
{
    PosixPath('a'): {
        PosixPath('b'): {PosixPath('c'): None},
        PosixPath('d'): None,
        PosixPath('e'): {
            PosixPath('f'): {PosixPath('g'): None, PosixPath('h'): None, PosixPath('i'): None, PosixPath('j'): None},
            PosixPath('k'): None,
            PosixPath('l'): None,
            PosixPath('m'): None,
            PosixPath('n'): {PosixPath('o'): None, PosixPath('p'): None, PosixPath('q'): None},
            PosixPath('r'): None
        },
        PosixPath('s'): None
    }
}
```

And here is the output with the second instance commented:

```py
{
    PosixPath('a'): {
        PosixPath('b'): {PosixPath('c'): None},
        PosixPath('d'): None,
        PosixPath('e'): {
            PosixPath('f'): {PosixPath('g'): None, PosixPath('h'): None, PosixPath('i'): None, PosixPath('j'): None},
            PosixPath('k'): None,
            PosixPath('l'): None,
            PosixPath('m'): None,
            PosixPath('n'): {PosixPath('o'): None, PosixPath('p'): None, PosixPath('q'): None},
            PosixPath('r'): None
        },
        PosixPath('s'): {PosixPath('t'): {PosixPath('u'): None}, PosixPath('v'): {PosixPath('w'): None, PosixPath('x'): None}, PosixPath('y'): None},
        PosixPath('z'): None
    }
}
```

When the dictionary ends at `PosixPath('s'): None` with the first instance commented, `next_count` is greater than `count`, and `prefix` is in the line `├───s`, so I'm wondering why that condition isn't triggering.